# Debug pytests in emacs

Tags: python, testing, debug

I try to debug my pytest-cases like this:

```
import pytest

def test_something()
    ...
    ...
    pytest.set_trace()
```

Then, i execute the tests by running `elpy-test`. The test starts to
run and stops at `pytest.set_trace()` - unfortunately the
**compilation** buffer is non-interactive and I'm stuck with a
debugger that I can't use...

What's the right way to run tests in the debugger, using emacs?

Answer (score 5):

I think that there are only the following solutions:

- Run tests outside of Emacs from your terminal emulator
- Run tests from [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud)
- Run tests inside Emacs via eshell. But shell output may be corrupted, so this not a good solution
- Run tests with [pytest-el](https://github.com/ionrock/pytest-el). It works good, but without autocompletion.

Comment: I've installed and tried realgut. It's nice, but I don't understand how I can use it to solve my problem :s

Comment: Run your tests with realgud :) For example you can run tests from Emacs shell and attach it to realgud session.

Comment: I added information about `pytest-el` to my answer.