How to jump to a failed test while testing python?
I know this is a pretty broad question and maybe even non-emacs related.
However I don't know where to start but develop python using dap-mode
Usually I have two buffers: sometest.py and a terminal running the test $ pytest.
Now if a test fails I have to read the line number from the terminal in order to manually jump to that line in the other buffer (sometest.py).
Isn't that something an IDE usually provides and how can I replicate it in emacs?

how have https://github.com/wbolster/emacs-python-pytest and https://github.com/ionrock/pytest-el failed you?

i'd flag this as a dupe of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/debug-pytests-in-emacs but i'd imagine the state-of-the-art is a bit better now
